# Running Selenium Tests using TestNG in parallel causes errors

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I am building a selenium grid framework using two VM's as nodes (chrome in one, Firefox in the other).  When I run my sample test in series, they work with no issues.  When I run them in parallel, however, the test in Chrome does only goes as far as to launch the website I'm testing but does nothing else, and the Firefox browser runs the test perfectly (prints the message at the end of the test to show me it passed, at least it should have passed.  When the suite is finished running, the test tells me chrome passed (it didn't) and Firefox throws an element not found exception.  I know my issue has something to do with keeping my threads from crossing, but this is My first time setting up anything like this and I have no idea how to debug it.

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
    <test verbose="2" name="Chrome">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
        <parameter name="nodeURL" value="http://10.11.25.170:5551/wd/hub"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test verbose="2" name="Firefox">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="nodeURL" value="http://10.11.25.170:5552/wd/hub"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Base.java

```
public class Base {

    public WebDriver driver = null;

    public WebDriver getDriver(String browserName, String nodeURL) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

        if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        } else if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        }

        caps.setBrowserName(browserName);
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);

        return driver;
    }
```

TestBase.java

```
public class TestBase extends Base {


    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"browserName", "nodeURL"})
    public void beforeTest(String browserName, String nodeURL) throws MalformedURLException {
        Base b = new Base();
        driver = b.getDriver(browserName, nodeURL);
        //driver = b.getLocalDriver();      
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest() {       
        driver.quit();
    }   
}
```

LoginTest.java

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void one() throws IOException {
        driver.get("http://company.com");

        EmailModal modal = new EmailModal();
        modal.cancelModal();

        Header header = new Header();
        header.clickSignInLink();

        System.out.println("Page Title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

EmailModalPage.java

```
public class EmailModalPage extends Base {
    public WebElement emailModalCancelButton() {
        return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='js-closeLayer closeLayer fr'")) ;  
        // ^^^ Line 11, where the error was thrown
    }
}
```

EmailModal.java

```
public class EmailModal extends EmailModalPage {
    public void cancelModal() {
        emailModalCancelButton().click();
    }
```

This is the error that was thrown when removing the static keyword:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.automation.ecom.pages.EmailModalPage.subscribeToEmailModal(EmailModal_.java:11)
```

Comment: Try removing the static keyword in the driver declaration in Base.java. That should generate a new driver for each test and avoid the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, but now that threw a `NullPointerException` on the  object definition behind the email modal (originally called in `LoginTest.java`.  I'm fairly new to Java, why do you think that is?  It worked with the static definition on `driver`.

Comment: Kind of hard to guess at without seeing the class for EmailModal.

Comment: I guess so...I have added the /EmailModal and EmailModalPage classes now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share the code for com.company.automation.ecom.pages.EmailModalPage class, method "subscribeToEmailModal()" from where this exception is arising.

Comment: The `driver` is not initialized in `EmailModalPage` and it is null.